# Chart not exporting to XLS File - Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

I have integrated Highcharts in my code to show data using charts.

HIghcharts displays chart on the website, it great. but when downloading data using their api it does not display chart in the xls file, it instead shows raw data in the excel, i want to show chart even in the xls file.

Pic1 shows how chart appears on my website. 
pic2 shows how the data appears when i download.

I need something to show the actual chart (which is shown on the site) to be in the excel too. [image]
[image]

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gx2y2.png):

Comment: Save your chart as an image and paste the image in Excel

Comment: Not a good idea..want to do it programmatically

Comment: Its the same excel can't use web representation directly unless you try to use VBA to add a web browser or an add-in.

Comment: is there any possiblity to make the chart available for download  ?

Comment: What do you mean by download ? If it's all the HTML and JS code the answer is no that not possible. If you try to embed a web page inside Excel look [here](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/387722-html-into-excel-post2742300.html?s=58d670b1f36d420e2aeb0abb42ceb2f6#post2742300)

Comment: You see the chart image ? currently that is shown on the web page, what i want is when i click on download button, the entire chart(populated by highcharts) should be  available in the xls too, right now upon download only raw data appears in the XLS file

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts does not provide a possibility to export a chart as an image to XLS file. You can export directly only the chart data. As @Core972 noticed, you can download a chart image and paste it in Excel.

> **Export module**
>
> ...
>
> Additionally there's the export data module that enables exporting the
>   chart data to CSV, XLS or HTML table formats.

**Docs:** https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/export-module-overview

Comment: using the export data module, i'll get the data in CSV right and not the chart?